# How can I implement Biometric API in Android?

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I want to use biometrics or password to lock/unlock images in my app. Biometric API can detect the biometrics but the "use password" option take the device's pin/password. I want the user to enter a password in-app and any password he wants.

Comment: What is the exact issue or problem statement? What are you finding difficult?

Comment: I want to give to option to lock/encrypt images. User can enter a password or he can use his biometrics. But the Biometric API will take the device's pin/password.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the negative button. I set the text of negative button to "Use Password" and handled the negative button onclick in the onAuthenticationError callback method.

```
if (errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON) {
    //show the in app password dialog
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using both biometrics and password in your app is a common pattern. Essentially the idea is to use Biometrics on devices that support it, and to use an Account/app password otherwise, like so:

```
override fun onClick(view: View) {  // user clicks a button in your app to authenticate
   val promptInfo = createPromptInfo()
   if (BiometricManager.from(context)
               .canAuthenticate() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS) {
       biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, cryptoObject)
   } else {
       loginWithPassword()
   }
}
```

In addition, when creating your PromptInfo you would do `.setNegativeButtonText(getString(R.string.prompt_info_use_app_password))` and then in the `onAuthenticationError()` callback you would do

```
override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
   super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
   Log.d(TAG, "$errorCode :: $errString")
   if(errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON) {
       loginWithPassword() // Because negative button says use account/app password
   }
}
```

Notice the use of `cryptoObject`. That's because a password or biometric authentication in itself does not encrypt your data. And so if you truly want your data -- in this case your photos -- to be private, you must encrypt them.

Then finally inside the `onAuthenticationSucceeded()` callback you would show your data

```
   override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
       super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
       Log.d(TAG, "Authentication was successful")
       // Proceed with viewing the private encrypted data.
       showEncryptedData(result.cryptoObject)
   }
```

*Disclaimer: I work for Android/Google, specifically on biometrics. I am available to answer your follow up questions*

Comment: also see this blog post: https://medium.com/@isaidamier/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd

Comment: I figured it out. I did the exact same thing. Handled the error code for Negative Button and set text of Negative button to use password. Then showed my password input dialog.

Comment: @IsaiDamier Is this the correct way? Is UmerMaqsood has done correctly?